# how to convert a list of strings into a list of variables?

Tags: python, pandas

Hi might be a simple question. How do i convert this:

```
mylist = ['table[0].df', 'table[1].df']
```

to this

```
mylist = [table[0].df, table[1].df]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using `eval`. For every item in the list, `eval()` is used and saved on the same location as the original string.

```
mylist = ['table[0].df', 'table[1].df']

for i, item in enumerate(mylist):
    mylist[i] = eval(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
new_list=list(map(lambda x:eval(x),my_list))
```